# Host two web sites under same domain name in IIS 8.5

Tags: .net, reactjs, .net-core, dns, iis-8

I have two web sites, one is a ReactJs frontend and the other is a .net Core web API.
I want to host ReactJs site under [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) and API under [www.mydomain.com/api](http://www.mydomain.com/api).
I created a virtual directory (converted to an application) called api and put the .net Core code in there, but React treats [www.mydomain.com/api](http://www.mydomain.com/api) as part of React site.
How can I achieve the above? Thanks

Comment: If you use the project template in VS to create a new project, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/react?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio you can see how React and ASP.NET Core can live in the same project and then deploy.

Comment: @LexLi thanks, is it possible to achieve what I want for two already developed web sites?

Comment: What does it mean that “React treats it as part of React site”?

Comment: You can try Nginx reverse proxy to use same domain with different path for front end and back end

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen For an example, the React site is protected by a login, so it asks me to login when I try to access www.mydomain.com/api. Thanks

Comment: Is the virtual directory defined as separate application or just a virtual directory? In any case I’d just use ASP.NET to serve the front end files since it will be a lot simpler than working with two applications in one host.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I have converted virtual directory to an application. The problem is two sites are already built, so I have to find a way to make this work. Thanks

Comment: They can be built entirely separately, the React site usually just needs a way to serve files and the API site is capable of doing that just by copying the files into it. So if that’s possible I’d go for that. Otherwise unfortunately can’t help without having access to check what exactly is the configuration etc